# How to copy password from Mono-executed KeePass2 to xterm on Linux?

Tags: linux, security, passwords, clipboard

I use KeePass2 to access username/password information in a Dropbox file. This allows convenient access from multiple devices. I can't seem to copy a password to the clipboard on my Linux 2.6.27.41-170.2.117.fc10.x86_64 system, however, in order to supply the password to a prompt in an xterm(1). I've tried both Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V and highlighting and mouse button 2 clicking. The KeePass2 program on the Linux system is executed by Mono.

How can I copy the password to the xterm(1)?

[Aside: I think we need a "KeePass" tag.]

ADDENDUM: My mouse buttons were misconfigured: button 2 wasn't set to "copy". Sorry for the false alarm.

Comment: It's a bit offtopic. Superuser would be better for this.

Comment: In my case, the packages `xdotool` and `xsel` did the trick, Source: http://superuser.com/a/939216/286021

Answer (score 0):

Middle mousebutton (probably your scrollbutton) **click** should work

On two-button mice it would be buttonl+buttonr simultanesously

Comment: I already tried that (highlighting and button 2 clicking).

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue, not with xterm, but with gnome-terminal in Ubuntu Desktop 11.10.

For me, Ctrl+Shift+Insert works as expected.

Try this with xterm.