# Can't paste in gnome-terminal from Keepas2 running via mono

Tags: clipboard, gnome-terminal, keepass, mono

I'm running OpenSUSE 13.2 and I'm using Keepass2. The app is runnig via mono. I want to copy my password from keepass to the terminal, however this isn't working using `CTRL + SHIFT + V`. This is a common problem but I can't find a proper solution.

Note that I won't run Keepassx as Keepas (.net) has many more features (e.g. KeepassHTTP).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why do you run keepass2 under wine? - you can install and run it native (just with mono)!

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean...... I just install it via my package manager..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution!

I can confirm this works on OpenSUSE and Arch Linux. I hope this works on other distro's too. I tried everything in this question [How can I merge the gnome clipboard and the X selection?](https://superuser.com/questions/68170/how-can-i-merge-the-gnome-clipboard-and-the-x-selection) but nothing helped. I found this bug at launchpad which worked: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/keepass2/+bug/1010289 .

**Solution:** Install both `xdotool` and `xsel`, and restart gnome-terminal and keepass2.

I tested this on `gnome-terminal`, `terminator` and `konsole`.

<s>EDIT: this solution works, however not for some Java based applications. (PHPStorm and other Jetbrains software) I solved this:
 - install `parcellite`
 - start it 
 - right click on the tray icon and choose `preferences` 
 - make sure `Use Copy (Ctrl+C)`, `Use Primary` and `Synchronise clipboards` are enabled.</s>

[image]

EDIT2: There is a better solution for the Java problem (thanks @colan), a patch has been merged into xsel but this hasn't been released (see: https://github.com/kfish/xsel/pull/6), but compiling from source is very easy:

1. first remove xsel using your package manager
2. clone the repo: `git clone https://github.com/kfish/xsel`
3. `cd xsel`
4. `touch README` (looks like the autogen script needs a README file, but can't found it)
5. `./autogen.sh`
6. `make`
7. `sudo make install`

You can manually test it: `echo "test" | xsel -i -b`.

This will install xsel into `/usr/loca/bin/`. Note that version 1.2.0 of xsel is not the correct version, this was released 9 years ago and doesn't include the patch! On arch linux you can use `xsel-git` from the AUR https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xsel-git/.

Comment: xdotool was installed, but xsel did the trick for me, too! I can confirm that i had the same problem and that this solution solved it on Debian Testing.

Comment: The Java issue is described at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/keepass2/+bug/1379877 .

Comment: @colan wow that's awesome. Compiling xsel from source resolves the issue!

Comment: I did all your steps to compile xsel from source and I get this `echo "test" | xsel -i -b.
bash: /usr/bin/xsel: No such file or directory
`. I manually copied it from `/usr/local/bin`, but my version is still `xsel version 1.2.0 by Conrad Parker <conrad@vergenet.net>
`